# About polynomials rings in F_2[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand how to find all congruence classes in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ modulo $x^2$. How can I compute them ? Can someone get me started with this? I am having trouble understanding $\mathbb{F}_2[x] $ is it the set $\{ f(x) = a_nx^n + ...+ a_1 x + a_0 : a_i = 0,1 \} $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over any field, and given any nonzero polynomial $g(x)$, the division algorithm says that, for any $f(x)\in F[x]$, there exist unique $q(x),r(x)\in F[x]$ such that 
$$f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)\;\;\;\deg r(x)<\deg g(x).$$
It follows that in the quotient ring $F[x]/(g)$ every congruence class has a unique representative $r(x)$ with $\deg r<\deg g$ because 
$$[f]=[gq+r]=[g][q]+[r]=[0][q]+[r]=[r].$$

In the particular case where $g(x)=x^2$, every congruence class has a unique representative of the form $ax+b$. Since $x^2=0$ in $F_2[x]/(x^2)$ we can compute
$$(ax+b)(cx+d)=acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd=(ad+bc)x+bd.$$

Comment: So, the four congruence classes in $F_2[x]$ mod $x^2$ are $0,1,x,x+1$ right ?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: Just to understand, is it right the descripition of the set $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ in my question?

Comment: Yes, that is the polynomial ring as a set. The coefficients are in the field with 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is an euclidian ring (there is a division with remainder like in $\mathbb Z$). Besides, if the degree of the polynomial $f(x)$ is $n$,then the ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$ has $2^n$ elements because there are $2^n$ remainders of the division by $f(x)$ (a.i. $2^n$ polynomials of degree less than $n$).

It follows that you have for $x^2$ just $4$ elements which are $0,1, x, x+1$ in your quotient.

NOTE.- The ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2)$ is not a field (it is easy to show that the only irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is $x^2+x+1$)

Comment: Thank you very much, Lisyarus. (In "remainder" I have doubted with "rest" and "residues" but nothing with the right "remainder". Thank you again).

Comment: What are the 4 elements in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is $x^2+x+1$?